# Object query language | execute both "order by" and "where" clauses

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

How do I sort out some data according to an where clause and a order by clause using object query language this is the query that I'm using but i'm not sure if it is working or not.

```
SELECT user from user.User as user WHERE user.status=1 order by user.username
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine. From the reference documentation:

> #### [14.11. The order by clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-ordering)
>
> The list returned by a query can be
>   ordered by any property of a returned
>   class or components:
>
> ```
> from DomesticCat cat
> order by cat.name asc, cat.weight desc, cat.birthdate
> ```
>
> The optional asc or desc indicate
>   ascending or descending order
>   respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be written more like

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`status` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`username`
```

This assumes you have a table called `users` and want to select all rows where `status` is `1`, ordered by the username column.